Python, aiogram, Inlinekeyboard как поймать обработчик нажатой кнопки
Всем доброго времени, сделал календарь на месяц, в Телеграм боте, вывожу кнопки через цикл.
button_week_day=[InlineKeyboardButton(text=y, callback_data='1') for y in list_day_week]

заранее подготовив список дней в месяце.
list_11 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28,
               29, 30]

вопрос, как мне отследить callback_data нажатой кнопки?

Вот как можно вписать callback_data в кнопку из list_11:
buttons = []
for i in range(len(list_11)):
    if i < len(list_day_week):  # Проверяем, что индекс не выходит за пределы list_day_week
        button = InlineKeyboardButton(text=list_day_week[i], callback_data=str(list_11[i]))
        buttons.append(button)

Таким образом, мы создаем инлайн-кнопку, где text берется из list_day_week, а callback_data — из list_11.
Теперь вы можете корректно доставать из callback_query.data значение из списка list_11 (я бы показал как это делать, но вы не указали какой библиотекой вы пользуетесь).

Доброго времени,aiogram

С данным вопросом разобрался,
появился новый,
смотрите, когда клиент выбирает свободные часы для записи в салон красоты, нужно чтоб те часы которые заняты, или не выводили или были с замочком.
подскажите, как такое можно реализовать?
делаю запрос в базу, чтоб достать часы которые уже заняты, далее предполагаю, что нужно сравнить со списком часов, и если время из базы есть в списке записи, то пометить его как занятое...вот тут пока я застрял..заране СПАСИБО!!!
